# CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting does not access parameters in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg

Tags: c#, azure

I have two Azure service worker roles written in C#. I need to load some configuration from ServiceConfiguration.cscfg files which is needed by both worker roles. I created a common class that reads the configuration parameters and uses it in both roles.
In both roles I do the following:
I added a custom property to ServiceDefinition.csdef as follows

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="CustomProperty"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

and set a value in ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg as follows

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="CustomProperty" value="local-value" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

In the code of the common class, I try to access this property by calling

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CustomProperty");
```

For some reason, this returns null in one role and returns the correct value in the other role. When it fails, it writes the following messages to output.

```
Getting "CustomProperty" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
Getting "CustomProperty" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.
```

Of course if I add it to app.config it would read it but this is not what I want to do. I tried to access the property by calling

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("CustomProperty");
```

Surprisingly, it worked in both roles and returned the correct value. I need to use the method "CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting" because it is more standard and because the common class can be also used in console applications where it reads configuration from app.config. What are the reasons that causes CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting to fail other than the property does not exist in the configuration files.

Comment: Are you running / debugging the role as a standalone project or within the emulator?  From memory, if its running in the emulator it will retrieve the value for the ServiceConfiguration - if you run the project outside of the emulator if will retrieve the value from the appropriate app.config/web.config.

Comment: I run both service roles from the emulator. What I understand is that it should use ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg if I run it locally in the emulator, and ServiceCOnfiguration.Cloud.cscfg if I publish it to Azure. It should not fall back to app.config if the configuration is there in the ServiceConfiguration file. In my case, one service role uses the ServiceConfiguration file while the other falls back to app.config although the configuration files are the same in both roles.

Comment: Did you come across a solution?  I too have CloudConfigurationManager fail to retrieve settings from the local.cscfg.  It seems intermittent.